# PostgreSQL - Combine Queries

Tags: postgresql, select

I have a query that I want to combine with another query but without success.

The first query returns all schema names which have the table named `status`:

```
select s.schema_name 
from   information_schema.schemata s 
where exists (select * 
              from information_schema.tables t 
              where t.table_schema = s.schema_name 
              and t.table_name = 'status')
```

In each status table is a column `lastLogin` which can be selected like this:

```
select "lastLogin" 
from   "someID".status 
where  "lastLogin" is not null
```

How can I get all values for `lastLogin` from all status tables from every schema?

Thanks in advance, Doobie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, since a schema name in an SQL query must be a constant value. You will have to construct the second query based on the result of the first query.

What you could do is construct the second query so that it uses `UNION` to query *all* tables called `status` in a single query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and expertise Mr. Albe!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a single query for the general problem where the number of schemes is unknown. But you may create a stored procedure for that. I assume `lastLogin` has the type `TIMESTAMP`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION list_last_logins() RETURNS SETOF TIMESTAMP AS $$
DECLARE
    the_row RECORD;
    the_statement TEXT;
    the_result RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR the_row IN SELECT t.schema_name FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE t.table_name = 'status'
    LOOP
        the_statement := FORMAT('SELECT "lastLogin" FROM %s.status WHERE "lastLogin" IS NOT NULL', the_row.schema_name);
        FOR the_result IN EXECUTE the_statement
        LOOP
            RETURN the_result."lastLogin";
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Since Postgres 9.5 the inner loop may be shortened to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION list_last_logins() RETURNS SETOF TIMESTAMP AS $$
DECLARE
    the_row RECORD;
    the_statement TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR the_row IN SELECT t.schema_name FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE t.table_name = 'status'
    LOOP
        the_statement := FORMAT('SELECT "lastLogin" FROM %s.status WHERE "lastLogin" IS NOT NULL', the_row.schema_name);
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE the_statement;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can now select all values with

```
SELECT * FROM list_last_logins();
```